# How to install java locally - no root - on linux, if possible?

Tags: java, linux, root

I need java 1.7 and server has only got 1.6. I have no root privileges. I tried to google out something but it seems like nobody was doing it. Can I somehow compile it or get ready binaries so I could put those into my PATH. Could you help? System is Redhat.

Comment: see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is quite easy...

Download the JDK as a tarball from Oracle (a simple google search will yield the link).

Unzip it somewhere in your $HOME (for instance, `$HOME/jdk`).

Set `JAVA_HOME` to the path of the root JDK install; then prepend `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `PATH`.

And off you go.

---

Here I have a particular setting insofar as I run three different major versions of the JDK: 6, 7, 8. For instance, here is my source file for setting the current shell to use Java 8:

```
$ cat ~/.jdk/8
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/sunjdk/1.8/current
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

And in `/opt/sunjdk/1.8` (given that `/opt/sunjdk` is writable by my user hence I don't need to be `root`):

```
$ ls -l /opt/sunjdk/1.8/* -d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 fge fge  11 Oct 30 10:09 /opt/sunjdk/1.8/current -> jdk1.8.0_25
drwxr-xr-x 1 fge fge 274 Mar 18  2014 /opt/sunjdk/1.8/jdk1.8.0_05
drwxr-xr-x 1 fge fge 274 Sep 18 02:44 /opt/sunjdk/1.8/jdk1.8.0_25
```

(and yes, I was `root` to begin with so as to grant write permissions for `/opt/sunjdk` to "my" user; if you have no such liberty, just create another directory in your home)

Comment: You can do the manual installation as well for OpenJDK. I did not find a download on the site itself, but here www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-linux/ you'll find the newest OpenJDK as .tar.gz.

Answer (score 6):

[Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) offers JRE and JDK also as *.tar.gz for Linux. I usually had success just downloading such a package, untarring/unzipping it (`tar -xzvf jdk-8u25.tar.gz`) and then running it, using the absolute path.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to accomplish this using conda.

[Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html) is an open-source package-manager by [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/), that according to the website:

> You do not need administrative or root permissions to install Anaconda if you select a user-writable install location.

You can search the package repo from a browser at [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org) or command line, for example here are the results for [JDK](https://anaconda.org/search?q=jdk).

For Linux, you would download this [installer](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh).  Here is a command line that will start the installer for convenience:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Once conda is installed, you can [install packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages). For example, to install the JetBrains Runtime OpenJDK build:

```
conda install -c anaconda openjdk
```

Other builds may be available from other channels in the repository.

The instructions above should give a working install, but the [Getting started](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html) guide is a good place to get started.  Conda uses the concept of environments to help manage versions and paths in a fairly simple and straightforward manner.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Although this is probably not the "right" answer to the question, it helped me greatly as I am indeed working with anaconda :)

Comment: I pulled mine from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openjdk

Answer (score 1):

> *export JAVA_HOME=/opt/sunjdk/1.8/current*
>   
>   *export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"*

For me this option only worked when I changed linux to use bash instead ksh. I don't know if this is some kind of configuration in my company, but when I tried to run via ksh using `"set"` command instead `"export"` to define path, It was set correctly with the path of my new Java installation, but when I typed `which java` the old version was showed. But, when I executed bash, and typed the `"export"`, it worked. So, if someone have the same problem to configure it using `set` command, **try to use bash with `export` command.** I am using Redhat 6.2.